# SELECT DISTINCT ON Simple Table Unique Values

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables, one with unique LTV (lifetime values) with around 3300 records and then the transaction log with more than 5000 transactions.

Whenever I run the following query it keeps showing me duplicate values. I just want to look up the person's first name and last name from the first column.

```
SELECT
SociAll.firstname,
SociAll.lastname,
SociLTV.Email,
SociLTV.LTV
FROM
SociAll
INNER JOIN SociLTV ON SociAll.Email = SociLTV.Email
```

Sometimes the same email address is repeated 3 or 4 times depending on the number of transactions from that given user, even though the LTV is the exact same value.

How can I have only 1 record per email address on this Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
SociAll.firstname,
SociAll.lastname,
SociLTV.Email,
Sum(SociLTV.LTV)
FROM
SociAll
INNER JOIN SociLTV ON SociAll.Email = SociLTV.Email
GROUP BY SociAll.firstName,SociAll.LastName,SociAll.Email
```

You can also use COUNT() or MIN(), or MAX() etc. on the last column.   If you don't care at all about the last column, remove it.

You can also do the following if you don't care at all about the SocilTV records

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    SociAll.firstname,
    SociAll.lastname,
    SociLTV.Email,
    FROM
    SociAll
    INNER JOIN SociLTV ON SociAll.Email = SociLTV.Email
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a sum of the LTV since the LTV already has the final value. To answer the question I had a list of lifetime values of each customer.

```
SELECT
SociAll.firstname,
SociAll.lastname,
SociLTV.Email,
SociLTV.LTV
FROM
SociAll
INNER JOIN SociLTV ON SociAll.Email = SociLTV.Email
GROUP BY SociAll.firstName,SociAll.LastName,SociAll.Email
```

If I wasn't comparing the two tables and simply had a list of transactions, this query works great. It's a derivative of your solution.

```
SELECT
SociAll.Email,
SociAll.firstname,
SociAll.lastname,
Sum(SociAll.Price) as LTV
FROM
SociAll
GROUP BY SociAll.firstName,SociAll.LastName,SociAll.Email
```

As I posed the question I was using a pre-established 'LTV' table export from a list of customers and their lifetime value from an excel spreadsheet.

Thank you so much for your contributions. I hope others find this post useful.